# Incorporating Google Groups code into a block

Tags: blocks, javascript

The following code is given by Google groups to embed a forum into a webpage. I'm wondering what the best way to add this to a block is?

```
<iframe id="forum_embed"
 src="javascript:void(0)"
 scrolling="no"
 frameborder="0"
 width="900"
 height="700">
</iframe>  

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("forum_embed").src =
 "https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/forum-name" +
 "&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=" +
 encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
</script>
```